# How to set the values to one setter method using Reflection without knowing class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

I am new to java reflection.I will directly come to the question.

This is my class

```
public class RequestClass{

@XmlElement(name="Request")
private Request mRequest;

public Request getRequest() {
    return mRequest;
}

public void setRequest(Request request) {
    this.mRequest= request;
}
```

this my another class in this I am passing RequestClass object here

```
//The supplied requestObject is of type RequestClass
Object initialize(Object requestObject) { 
    //requestObject
}
```

In this code I want to manipulate, dynamically, the `request` property of the `RequestClass`. I don't know how to proceed further, so if anyone could provide some guidance, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this `requestObject.getClass().getMethod(method_name).invoke(requestObject);`

also, there is an overload of `getMethod` & `invoke`, through which you can pass parameter to that method (like in setters)